# how to create dynamic reports in java desktop application

Tags: java, mysql, frameworks, report

I am creating java desktop application. in the application i want to create many reports with different parameters. **which framework is easy to use and supports for desktop application.i am new to this concept.**

Comment: what is the difference between ireport and source forge dynamic report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/) is quite well known and should help you do what you need:

> JasperReports is the world's most popular open source reporting
>   engine. It is entirely written in Java and it is able to use data
>   coming from any kind of data source and produce pixel-perfect
>   documents that can be viewed, printed or exported in a variety of
>   document formats including HTML, PDF, Excel, OpenOffice and Word.

Comment: whether we can view the report file inside the java frame?

Comment: @Siddharth: You could render your reports in a PDF format and then either use the systems default PDF renderer (recommended) or else refer to some other tool such as [JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/). Also, I have never used these technologies, so you will have to make some of your own research.